# Swift function parameters naming

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say there is a function

```
func set(object: Class) { }
```

and we have a class

```
class Foo {
    var object: Class?
    func set(object: Class) { 
        self.object = object
    }
}
```

the question is how to avoid `self.object = object` line of code, since Swift recommends not to use `self` keyword besides closures with `self` reference - and it really improves code readability. Currently I achieve this like

```
class Foo {
    var object: Class?
    func set(_object: Class) { 
        object = _object
    }
}
```

but is there any other common way (I couldn't find one)?

## EDIT

since the question is not clear, another example

```
class Foo {
    let object: Class
    init(object: Class) { 
        self.object = object
    }
}
```

Is there any other common way of naming to avoid `self` keyword usage?

Comment: Like this: `func set(object anyNameYouCanThinkOf: Class) { object = anyNameYouCanThinkOf }`?

Comment: **since Swift recommends not to use self keyword besides closures with self reference - and it really improves code readability.** this is wrong Because you are not using closures. +

Comment: There is nothing wrong using self there. Btw you should create an initializer not an instance method called set

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I follow raywenderlich style guide https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#use-of-self

Comment: @LeoDabus it just an example. yeah, there is nothing wrong using `self`, but I wonder if there is a common way not to use it, if not - let it be.

Comment: Your code has not any issues. use init method that is recommended

Comment: Just use a struct instead

Comment: @LeoDabus god, instead of what, let's say it is initialiser, the question is about `self` keyword and way of avoiding it.

Comment: No reason to downvote this "opinionated" question, but for me `self.object = object` **is** a good example of readability. It's better than `object = object`, which is both syntactically correct and executes. One other way to do this is to use `func set(_ object: Class)`. It may not improve readability inside the function, but it will improve the call to it. (Even better, declare it as `func setObject(to: Class)`).

Comment: To avoid using self keyword you would need a parameter name different from the class property

Comment: @dfd the question is not about what is best, but if there is a way, looks like no, and it is totally fine, thanks for an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. I'm not sure where you see that Swift recommendation thing but even with that, what you are doing is not violating it since you are using self keyword within the init closure.

Second, there is no need to avoid using self keyword in your example. You usage of self keyword is totally valid and reliable. This is just like the `this` keyword in java if that makes more sense. How about this in java?

```
public class Foo {
    Object object;

    Foo(Object object){
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

Lastly, my take is that to avoid using self keyword unless it's needed like your example, where you have the same naming. The compiler will not be happy if you are not using the self keyword in your case. This rule will make sure that your code is as clean as possible, since you can put the self keyword in front of a lot of things and make them messy.

In conclusion, it's really up to you in this case. Both of your examples are good and none of them are bad practices.

Comment: What is the “init closure”? Do you mean the initializer body/code block?

Comment: @idmean Yes. I was talking about the Edit. Just reallized that the previous two examples are not talking about init methods but that's ok